# Power BI: Count numbers by Today, and the count numbers of the previous years at the same date

Tags: powerbi, comparison, dax

I'm new to Power BI and DAX.

I want to show the total ID count of this year and the total ID counts of previous years at the same dates each of which is associated with a different Category_Number.

The below tables show the original data set (1st table) and the result table (2nd table) I would like to have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0xi.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrGn.png)

Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you put the same image twice.

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter and use [SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax).

To get the values of one category you can do:

```
Category_Nbr 80 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(myTable),myTable[Category_Nbr] = 80)
```

for the value of this but for the previous year you could use your **DATE TABLE** if you have it, if not, use the automatic one. I'll assume you don't have one so use the automatic.

```
Category_Nbr 80 LY = CALCULATE([Category_Nbr 80],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(myTable[Effective_Date].Date))
```

With this you can do a comparison over time

```
Category_Nbr Count YoY = DIVIDE([Category_Nbr 80 LY]-[Category_Nbr 80],[Category_Nbr 80 LY])
```

You can just adapt the filter for other categories.

Consider having a look into [Quick Measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/power-bi/desktop-quick-measures) really nice way to start learning DAX.

Comment: I do have a calendar table. I tried your second measure with the SAMEPERIODYEAR function, but it didn't work. 
It's my fault that I didn't explain my question very clearly. I want to know how many IDs have the Category_Nbr= 80 and Effective_Dates by today (the Effective_Dates could be last year but cannot be future dates), how many IDs had the Category_Nbr=70 and Effective_Dates by the same date last year (it includes all the Effective_Dates before the same date last year. It could be two/three years, but could not be after the 4/17/2019).

Comment: @NewStart2020 and is it marked as a Date Table and related to Effective_date? Whats the name of that Table and the date column?

Answer (score 0):

Below are two measures I created.

The Total_ID measure works well. It shows the total number of IDs that have the Category_Number =80 and Effecitve_Date < Today.

The Total_ID_LY measure shows the total number IDs that have the Category_Number = 70, but doesn't show the Effective_Date< The same data last year.

I want the Total_ID_LY measure to have two filters, Category_Number = 70 (80-10) and Effective_Date < The same data last year of today.

Any helps?
Thanks!

Total_ID = COUNT('myTable'[ID])

Total_ID_LY =
VAR CurrentCategory = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'myTable'[Category_Number] )
VAR PreviousCategory =
CALCULATE (
MAX ( 'myTable'[Category_Number] ),
ALLSELECTED ( 'myTable' ),
KEEPFILTERS ( 'myTable'[Category_Number] < CurrentCategory )
)
VAR Result =
CALCULATE (
[Total_ID],
'myTable'[Category_Number] = PreviousCategory
)
RETURN
Result